# Is it possible to add a member to a distribution (mailing) list with Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using Microsoft Azure and more specifically Active Directory. I'm currently using Python and the Graph REST API to create users. I would also like to add them to a mailing list in Exchange but by searching through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-beta#security-groups-and-mail-enabled-security-groups) for hours and looking at various SO post it seems it's not supported. So I'm now looking at different Python libraries to possibly achieve that and haven't really found an answer.

Could someone please bring some light to this issue and perhaps show an example? All I'd like to do is to somehow programmatically and using Python add a member to a mailing list. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Revert to a solved problem.. I'm certain you can do this using Powershell, and pretty sure you could run a Powershell script from Python.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is not an official MS Graph SDK for Python.

You can refer to the Python sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python).

For this application, you will use the [Requests-OAuthlib](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to make calls to Microsoft Graph.

This sample is to get the events in O365.

```
def get_calendar_events(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)

  # Configure query parameters to
  # modify the results
  query_params = {
    '$select': 'subject,organizer,start,end',
    '$orderby': 'createdDateTime DESC'
  }

  # Send GET to /me/events
  events = graph_client.get('{0}/me/events'.format(graph_url), params=query_params)
  # Return the JSON result
  return events.json()
```

What you need to modify is to call [Add a member to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-add-a-member-to-a-group)